# How do I add dynamic SEF URLs to Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out how to add dynamic SEF URLs to a rails 3.1 project I've been working on. I haven't been able to find much via google.

Any guidance or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. But you can simply use gem for that purpose https://github.com/norman/friendly_id, Ryan Bates have a cast about it http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid .